# If else if, code only resolves to else condition

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a pretty basic text adventure to test my rudimentary skills. The basic movement prompts user input, and if it matches certain strings, changes their coordinates. I know, it's stupid. But the `if`, `else if`, `else` for matching their response always returns `else`, even if you enter one of the matching strings.

```
string action;
string west = "go west";
string east = "go east";
string north = "go north";
string south = "go south";
string prompt = "Don't just stand around with your dagger in your ass! Do something! ";

//i wrote a bunch of setup story here, it's irrelevant text output

int vertical = 25;
int horizon = 20;

//action begins
start:
{
cout << "What do you do?" << endl;
cin >> action;

if (action == south)
{
    vertical = vertical - 5;
    goto descriptions;
}
else if (action == east)
{
    horizon = horizon + 5;
    goto descriptions;
}
else if (action == west)
{
    horizon = horizon - 5;
    goto descriptions;
}
else if (action == north)
{
    vertical = vertical + 5;
    goto descriptions;
}
else
{
    cout << prompt << "(Try typing \"go\" followed by a direction)" << endl;
    goto start;
}

description:
//i put a bunch of if, else if, else stuff about coordinates describing the area down here.
```

When I type "go east" or "go north", it prints the prompt string about daggers and asses, which should only print if i type something else.
What am I doing wrong? To clarify, I'm using Xcode on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: Why are you using a `goto` and where is the `descriptions` label?

Comment: yeah, please dont ever use `goto`

Comment: Don't listen to these "never use `goto`" zealots. They are trying to misteach you to think in gross generalisations (rather than thinking for yourself in the moment) in order to bolster their own chosen worldview.

Comment: Don't say don't use gotos' , they've use cases , but use them only when you have an utterly complex solution as an alternative to them. Also use them when you know what you're doing. @dwcanillas I presume that you know what is working under the hoods?

Comment: This isn't even a bad example of their use, frankly. Anyway, use your debugger to examine the value of `action`.

Comment: Assuming the `description` label is supposed to be the one the `goto` statements jump to, `if` and `else` already handle that, so it's completely redundant. As for `start` and the last `goto`, it should most likely be a simple loop and maybe a `continue` statement.

Comment: @chris: It's clearer than a nest of loops and implicit flows. It's explicit. It says "go here, do that". Perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @TBohne (sorry for the inappropriate comment about Java).

Comment: You might also consider a Switch Case over if else if else if [...] else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cin >> string` reads one word at a time, not one line. So if the input contains "go north", the first `>>` will read "go" and the second "north", neither of which are equal to "go north".

Use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a whole line.

Comment: Thanks. What's the correct syntax for getline? Would it be `getline >> action;`? EDIT: I figured it out.

Comment: @Cameron No, no `<<`. Just `getline(cin, action)`.

Answer (score 7):

Value of `action` read from input would only be `"go"`, it stops on first whitespace character. See [behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) of `operator>>`.